# Editable Row Issue on primeNG table

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng

In my angular project, I use primeNG library 
I'm trying to make the rows editable in the data table so I follow the documentation
[https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/table/edit] to do that but I face issue I tried to solve it but I failed.

when I click in the edit button all rows become editable and supposed to be only the row was clicked on?

so how can I do it and send new data to the server

my code in **stackpiltz**
[https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1suual?file=src%2Fapp%2Fsuppliers-info%2Fsuppliers-info.component.ts]

For clarification

when I click modify button
[image]
it will be like that
[image: it will be like that]

thanks in advance for any cooperation

Comment: Stackblitz demo is not working , can you check

Comment: Yes is it, excuse me I use it for the first time, I think the problem in import service and model, can you help me?

Comment: I have fixed the import errors, still some functions are missing - you need to fix them by copying the local code correctly- https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tq7rmc

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Issue is with the dataKey you added, It should be UNIQUE existing property name in the data. Since col.field is not existing and null always , it is editing all rows.

It should be changed from

```
<p-table [value]="suppliers" [columns]="cols" editMode="row" dataKey="col.field">
```

to

```
<p-table [value]="suppliers" [columns]="cols" editMode="row" dataKey="id">
```

Here is the demo - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tq7rmc

Comment: I still need your help the edit happens in client-side only and I have this error < PUT http://localhost:4200/api/clints/0 404 (Not Found)

Comment: can you check the demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tq7rmc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fsuppliers-info%2Fsuppliers-info.component.html

Comment: that error is related to your backend api , check whether you backend server is running and check api/clints/ end point is available :)